# macOS: how to verify software downloads with public key? [LibreOffice_7.3.7]

Tags: mac, encryption, download, libreoffice

sry for wall of text... noob here (*^.^*) trying to learn about PGP / verifying download ‘LibreOffice_7.3.7_MacOS_x86-64.dmg’ on macOS? I think I know how to verify the download(?) but trying to understand how to utilise a public key. Quite a few online tutorials include importing a public keys but is it necessary as I couldn't get it to work?

What I did..

1. Installed brew and gnupg
2. Downloaded ‘LibreOffice_7.3.7_MacOS_x86-64.dmg’
3. Downloaded their PGP signature as: ‘LibreOffice_7.3.7_MacOS_x86-64.dmg.asc’
4. Downloaded their shasum as: LibreOffice_7.3.7_MacOS_x86-64.dmg.sha256.txt

Navigated to downloads folder and tried..

```
$ gpg --import LibreOffice_7.3.7_MacOS_x86-64.dmg.asc
```

But it returned…

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Figured on their website is the --pgp signature-- not their public.asc (doh!). After googling found [this](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/where-is-a-fingerprint-for-libreoffice-public-pgp-key/18124/5) discussion which lead to [Christian Lohmaier](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/libreoffice/2015-February/066756.html)’s comment saying:

Public key =

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys AFEEAEA3
```

and fingerprint is: C283 9ECA D940 8FBE 9531  C3E9 F434 A1EF AFEE AEA3

So I tried...

```
$  gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys AFEEAEA3
gpg: key F434A1EFAFEEAEA3: "LibreOffice Build Team (CODE SIGNING KEY) <build@documentfoundation.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

$ gpg --fingerprint AFEEAEA3
pub   rsa4096 2010-10-11 [SC]
      C283 9ECA D940 8FBE 9531  C3E9 F434 A1EF AFEE AEA3
uid           [ unknown] LibreOffice Build Team (CODE SIGNING KEY) <build@documentfoundation.org>
sub   rsa4096 2010-10-11 [E]

$ gpg --verify LibreOffice_7.3.7_MacOS_x86-64.dmg.asc LibreOffice_7.3.7_MacOS_x86-64.dmg    
gpg: Signature made Sun 30 Oct 10:56:45 2022 GMT
gpg:                using RSA key C2839ECAD9408FBE9531C3E9F434A1EFAFEEAEA3
gpg: Good signature from "LibreOffice Build Team (CODE SIGNING KEY) <build@documentfoundation.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: C283 9ECA D940 8FBE 9531  C3E9 F434 A1EF AFEE AEA3
```

I also tried:

```
$ shasum -a 256 LibreOffice_7.3.7_MacOS_x86-64.dmg
```

and the output had same number as the one I downloaded. However...

**TLDR:** Although I could download the ---pgp signature--- as a .asc file to compare with the .dmg Is this method ok and how do I utilise the public key? Why was the ---public key--- not on the libreoffice website?